# editors for tables in Sphinx/reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm looking at using Sphinx / reStructuredText for documentation, and it looks very promising, except tables look like a pain to do. Is there an editor that can help?

Comment: With Vim's rectangular selection (visual block) it works kind of easy.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs acts as the default (or the most natural choice) for editing reStructuredText. With that in mind  [table mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode) meshes pretty well with the way reST do tables.

Answer (score 2):

[ReSTedit](http://python.net/~gherman/ReSTedit.html) is good and simple if you're using a Mac.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText#Dedicated_reStructuredText_Editors) lists others.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to me is vscode with plugin and venv

1. plugin for preview

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lextudio.restructuredtext

2. plugin for automatic completion

https://github.com/yishenggudou/quick-sphinx-vscode-extension