# Which editor can align tables in reStructuredText for Sphinx?

Tags: emacs, editor, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, ascii-art

I tried several editors to write reStructuredText for Sphinx documentation, but found none with a comprehensive support of the reST capabilities.

Which editor can align tables while typing?

The Emacs combination `rest-mode` + `table-mode` for example has many bugs and does not support [Sphinx tables](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#tables) with `=` like:

```
+--------+--------+
| Letter | Number |
| (any)  | (>1)   |
+========+========+
| a      | 9      |
+--------+--------+
| c      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716232/), but mine aims on an editor that also can manage `=` in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Vim and the [Unicode-RST-Tables](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Unicode-RST-Tables) plugin you can do this without issue.

In vim one assigns a  that usually is at the defaul "\". I will assume that is the case here. Once you have installed Unicode-RST-Tables it is a matter of:

`\\c` to create the table and whenever you have changed the content issuing `\\f` to rearrange the table.